# Returning Optional<Student> or Optional.empty()

Tags: java-8, option-type

I'm playing a little bit with Optional to understand how it works. Let's say I have this class:

```
public class Student {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Student(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and I want to return a Student by Id or Optional.empty if it doesn't find it. This is what I have so far:

```
public class Main {
    static List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        students.add(new Student(1, "name1"));
        students.add(new Student(2, "name2"));
        students.add(new Student(3, "name3"));

        System.out.println(getStudentById(1).get().getName());
    }

    public static Optional<Student> getStudentById(int id) {
        return students
                .stream()
                .filter( s -> s.getId() == id)
                .findFirst();
    }
}
```

That works but I wanted to add this line:

```
.findFirst()
.orElse(Optional.empty());
```

and I got this:
    Error:(23, 39) java: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that java.util.Optional conforms to com.company.Student

Also I'd like to know if that is the correct way to go over a list, I mean element by element or there is something better?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I'm using java 8

Comment: `findFirst` will return optional if there is nothing in the stream https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--

Comment: Great, Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read javadocs of [Stream#findFirst()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) you will find that you already have what you need:

> Returns an Optional describing the first element of this stream, or an
>   empty Optional if the stream is empty. If the stream has no encounter
>   order, then any element may be returned.

So just do

```
return students
            .stream()
            .filter( s -> s.getId() == id)
            .findFirst();
```